# How to close the pop up window when I click outside window in wpf in mahapps?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, flyout

I have a Flyoout popup window and Test window in my WPF application. What I need is, I need to close the window when I click outside of the Flyout. I set Panel.Zindex to visible top. I have tried a code which is working fine. But it doesn't know whether I click inside the Flyout or outside the flyout window. Its closing when ever i click inside main screen.!

Here is my xaml code:

```
xmlns:metro="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

 <metro:Flyout x:Name="flyOutControl" IsOpen="False" Background="#5D7BA5"      Foreground="White"
                                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="50"
                                  Width="400" Height="auto">


                            <TreeView x:Name="treeviewBreadcrumb" Width="350"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"
                                      Background="Transparent" Foreground="White"                                 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top">

                                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>                                            
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>                                            
                                    </Style>
                                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>                                    

                            </TreeView>

                    </metro:Flyout>
```

If i am in Test window screen, I can set a Isopen property to true this Flyout.
how can i close this if i click outside of any other window?

Any help would be really appriciated.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: check if metro:Flyout has IsLightDismissEnabled property. If yes set it to true. Or if u have in your control classic popup set this property to true.

Comment: I dont have this property.

Comment: try to check if exist property IsPinned

Answer (score 7):

Set isPinned property to false on your flyout like so:

```
<metro:Flyout IsPinned="False"></metro:Flyout>
```